# How to reuse a jQuery object (newbie)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I correctly access an object once it has been instantiated :

Im implementing jCrop and need to run it twice on the page - (first time sets a default box & second sets the box in the middle of the image)

So I need to create the jCrop object and be able to access its properties later, here is my code so far :

```
    var myJcrop;
if (cropperInit == true) {
    getjCropSize();

    //Start up jCrop on the image, specifying our function be called when the selection rectangle changes,
    myJcrop = image.Jcrop({
        setSelect: [10, 10, 50, 50],
        aspectRatio: 1,
        onChange: update,
        onSelect: update,
        bgFade: 'true'
    });
} else {
    alert("cropperInit = false");
    myJcrop({
        setSelect: [startX, startY, boxWH, boxWH],
        aspectRatio: 1,
        onChange: update,
        onSelect: update,
        bgFade: 'true'
    });
}
```

The jCrop object is created OK in the first 'if block' but the second 'else if' block isn't working.

**EDIT:**

After digging about, jCrop has an API for this, its used like this :

```
var jCropApi;
image.Jcrop({
    setSelect: [10, 10, 10, 10],
    aspectRatio: 1,
    onChange: update,
    onSelect: update,
    bgFade: 'true'
}, function () {
    jCropApi = this;
});

jCropApi.animateTo([startX, startY, boxWH, boxWH]);
```

Thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your else clause you're not using `myJcrop = image.Jcrop({`, you're only writing `myJcrop({`.  In other words, you're only creating an object in the first clause.

You don't even need to declare objects in each clause, why don't you just adjust the variables:

```
var myJcrop;

if (cropperInit == true) {
    getjCropSize();
    var setSelectArray = [10, 10, 50, 50];
} else {
    alert("cropperInit = false");
    // Make sure startX, startY, etc. are set
    var setSelectArray = [startX, startY, boxWH, boxWH],
}
myJcrop = image.Jcrop({
   setSelect: setSelectArray,
   aspectRatio: 1,
   onChange: update,
   onSelect: update,
   bgFade: 'true'
});
```

Comment: If I declare it again in the where clause I get two jCrop boxes on the image, im thinking im doing this all wrong.

Comment: Hi Jamie, the only way I can perform getjCropSize(); is if jCrop has ran, when it runs it creates an image that im using to calculate the center of the image, I then re-run jcrop to position the box on the image (using the newly created coords), I don't think this is a good approach, im a newbie with all this but im looking at a callback function instead of this mess.

Answer (score 1):

Those two blocks of code are exclusive, only one of them should ever run, so the jCrop object you think is created in the if block wont ever be created if the logic flows though the else block.

You'll need to declare the jCrop object as a new object in each logic block.

Comment: Im setting the cropperInit bool so I know first time is true, subsequently its false.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you might need to move your myJcrop variable to a more global state (like your cropperInit variable). Is this chunk of code in a function that gets executed twice?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
var myJcrop;

if (cropperInit == true) {
    getjCropSize();

    //Start up jCrop on the image, specifying our function be called when the selection rectangle changes,
    var options = {
        setSelect: [10, 10, 50, 50],
        aspectRatio: 1,
        onChange: update,
        onSelect: update,
        bgFade: 'true'
    };
} else {
    alert("cropperInit = false");
    options = {
        setSelect: [startX, startY, boxWH, boxWH],
        aspectRatio: 1,
        onChange: update,
        onSelect: update,
        bgFade: 'true'
    };
}

myJcrop = image.Jcrop(options);
```